# How to show annotations in a pdf using pdfium viewer?

Tags: c#, winforms, pdf, pdf-annotations, pdfium

I am using PDfiumViewer winform control to display pdfs. And, I have added some annotations to the pdf, but those do not show up in the pdfviewer control.So, how can achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem using the following code:

```
doc = PDDocument.load(FilePath);
PDPage page = (PDPage)doc.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages().get(pageNum);
int rotPD = page.findRotation();
PDRectangle pageBound = page.findCropBox();
PDRectangle rect = ModifyRectAccordingToRotation(rectangle, rotPD, pageBound);
PDAnnotationLink txtLink = new PDAnnotationLink();
    PDBorderStyleDictionary borderULine = new PDBorderStyleDictionary();
                    borderULine.setStyle(PDBorderStyleDictionary.STYLE_UNDERLINE);
borderULine.setWidth(0);
txtLink.setBorderStyle(borderULine);
PDActionRemoteGoTo remoteGoto = new PDActionRemoteGoTo();
PDComplexFileSpecification fileDesc = new PDComplexFileSpecification();
fileDesc.setFile(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(path));
remoteGoto.setOpenInNewWindow(true);
remoteGoto.setFile(fileDesc);
txtLink.setAction(remoteGoto);
txtLink.setRectangle(rect);
page.getAnnotations().add(txtLink);
```

Comment: I do not see the PDAnnotationLink. Where is that from? I am unable to show annotations using PdfRenderFlags.Annotations.

Answer (score 4):

In PDFium there is an FPDF_ANNOT flag that can be passed to the various FPDF_RenderPage* methods. It's possible the PDFiumViewer code provides the same flag somewhere.

Comment: I am unable to render annotations using when using PDFiumSharpV2 page.Render(bitmap, PageOrientations.Normal, RenderingFlags.Annotations); Do you have any ideas on why the flags seems to make no difference in rendering?

Comment: Sorry, I don't now anything about PDFiumSharpV2, and I haven't worked on PDFium in 5ish years at this point.

Answer (score 1):

In 'public Image Render' method under the PdfDocument.cs class use below code

[image]

Comment: I am unable to show annotations when using Render(... , PdfRenderFlags.Annotations). Any ideas on why the flag is seemingly ignored?

Comment: It works. replacing FROM: (flags & PdfRenderFlags.Annotations) != 0 TO:  (flags & PdfRenderFlags.Annotations) == 0. Pdf show up correctly. Now may have other way to do it but I was unable find.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a PdfiumViewer version greater than or equal to 2.13.0.0, you can find the answer from the RenderPDFPageToBitmap method of the source file PdfFile.cs

[PdfFile.cs](https://github.com/pvginkel/PdfiumViewer/blob/master/PdfiumViewer/PdfFile.cs)